# USB game controller/gamepad not detected or seen at all

Tags: windows-7, usb

I have a uCom DualShock USB gamepad that I bought when I first started using a Windows 7 computer. It worked like a breeze. Then I tried using it with a Windows XP device. It said USB device not recognized, so I gave up.

The next time I tried using it on my Windows 7 computer it wasn't detected; no sound effects, nothing. Then I checked "Devices and Printers"; it wasn't there. At first I thought the cable was damaged, but when I took it to a Windows 8 system it was detected but not recognized.

What I want to know is why is it not detected on my Windows 7 PC anymore.

Comment: try a different usb port.  Sometimes these things can be finicky.  I have a keyboard at work that just refuses to function on a certain usb port, even though any other device works fine there

Comment: i have tried all ports the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Same proplem here , I think the proplem is the windows version , if you tried it on xp or any other version it will work I think.

Comment: You don't sound too sure about this.  The site's Q&A format is based on answers being definitive solutions to the question.  Speculative suggestions of things to try can be posted in a comment (with a little more rep), and can be moved to an answer if it proves to be a solution.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. He already tried it on XP and said it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

May be its because you are useing more than one port in your machine.sometimes overload of devices plugged in ,in your machine can lead to this problem.
Try removeing one or more device.